# Is it possible to have ShowButton and EditButton in one column in Datagrid of react-admin?

Tags: datagrid, multiple-columns, react-admin

Simple question, I am using `react-admin` and I am developing a list view of some data.

```
      <DatagridConfigurable preferenceKey="userList">
        <TextField source="email" />
        <TextField source="firstName" />
        <TextField source="lastName" />
      
        <ShowButton />
        <EditButton />
      </DatagridConfigurable>
```

Currently `ShowButton` and `EditButton` are displayed in two different columns. In the example listed by [react-admin documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html) it seems that those two buttons are in one column. But I could not find in the documentation how to do that. Is it possible somehow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<>
  <ShowButton />
  <EditButton />
</>
```